# Why this expectation inequality holds?

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

Can someone explain me how to obtain the following result:

[image]

where $E\mid X\mid^p<\infty$, $E\mid Y\mid^q<\infty$, $p,q>1$ and $1/p+1/q<1$.

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that, by definition, $I(\mid Y\mid>C)^k=I(\mid Y\mid>C)$ for any real number $k>0$. Maybe it can help.

It's in  [Corollary A.2's proof](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/MartingaleLimitTheoryAndItsApplication.pdf) of this book (pp. 278).

Given $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, for any $w\in\Omega$, it holds $C^{p'}I(\lvert Y\rvert>C)\leq \lvert Y\rvert^{p'}I(\lvert Y\rvert>C)$ where $p'=p/(p-1)$, by the definition of indicator/characteristic function,i.e.,  $\lvert Y\rvert^{p'}\geq C^{p'}$ when $\lvert Y\rvert> C$. Taking expectations and using Markov's inequality, $$E(C^{p'}I(\lvert Y\rvert>C))=C^{p'}P(\lvert Y\rvert>C)\leq C^{p'-q} E\lvert Y\rvert^q.$$
If I had $C^{p'}I(\lvert Y\rvert>C)\geq \lvert Y\rvert^{p'}I(\lvert Y\rvert>C)$, which is not true, the result would follow. Now, I'm suspecting that this result doesn't hold.

Comment: Sounds like an application of [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_for_probability_measures)

Comment: I'm thinking about it. Maybe Markov's inequality too?

Answer (score 1):

Put $p'=p/(p-1)$. By Holder's and Markov's inequalities
\begin{align}
E(\lvert X \rvert^{p'} I(\lvert X \rvert>C))&\leq [E\lvert X\rvert^{r}]^{p'/r} (P(\lvert X\rvert>C))^{1-p'/r}\\
&\leq  [E\lvert X\rvert^{r}]^{p'/r}  [E(\lvert X \rvert^r/C^r)]^{1-p'/r}\\
&=E\lvert X \rvert^r C^{p'-r},
\end{align}
the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p'=p/(p-1)$. The condition on $p$ and $q$ can be written as $q>p'$. We thus have to prove that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[Z^{p'}I(Z>C)\right]\leqslant C^{-q+p'}\mathbb E\left[Z^q\right],
$$
where $Z=\left\lvert Y\right\rvert$. This follows by taking the expectation on both sides in the inequality 
$$
Z^{p'}I(Z>C)\leqslant C^{-q+p'} Z^q.
$$

Comment: I don't think it helped too much.

Comment: Did you manage to see why the last displayed inequality is true? And how it could be useful?

Comment: Yes, but didn't get anything :(

Comment: I think I realize what is going on, using my comment (in my question). I will write it.

Comment: take a look in the answer below ,please.